# Invertible sheaves and global sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This question is from Liu's book on Algebraic Geometry.
Let $\mathcal{L}$ be an invertible sheaf on a scheme X. Suppose that X is an algebraic variety over a field k and that there are n points of X that are not basepoints for $\mathcal{L}$ . Show that if k is either infinite or with cardinality greater than n, there exists a section $s \in H^0(X,\mathcal{L})$ that generates $\mathcal{L}$ at these n points that are mot basepoints.

Comment: Hint:If $x$ is not a basepoint for $\mathcal{L}$, then the global sections that do *not* generate $\mathcal{L} _{x}$ form a *proper* subspace $V_{x} \subseteq H^{0}(X, \mathcal{L})$. If there is no section that generates $L _{x_{i}}$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$, then $\cup _{i} V_{x_{i}} = H^{0}(X, \mathcal{L})$. Is this possible?

Comment: Piotr: I suspect not, but I am not sure why. Is it analogous to where a vector space over an infinite field is not a union of finitely many proper subspaces? How could I see that the global sections are a vector space over k? (Probably easy?)

Comment: Well, normally when people say *invertible sheaf*, they assume that the sheaf in question is an $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-module. Thus,  $\mathcal{L}(X)$ is an $\mathcal{O}_{X}(X)$-module and a $k$-vector space in particular. And yes, this is completely analogous to the proof that over an infinite field a vector space is a not a finite union of proper subspaces. The proof will also work in this case.